# screenfull not expanding the video in Safari 14

Tags: reactjs, safari, react-player

I built a custom video player based on `react-player` lib but there is a problem in Safari browser that you can see on the screenshot. It does seem to enable the full-screen mode but the controls are in the wrong place and the video itself is not expanded. What could be the problem?
[image]

Comment: you got the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set width and height for video tag 100%